# Number Formatting to get rid of Integral and only show Decimal

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm doing a fancy graph where I want to show the % of Plan above a bar chart, but of course since it is a % the number is WAYYY lower than it should be.

I thought of a potentially cool hack where I combine the Results with the % of Plan, which would bump it up above the Results.

Where this is failing though is that I need to use custom number formatting so that I can omit what's before the decimal (Integral) and then show the rest as a percentage.

So for example if:

```
a) Plan = 500
b) Results = 600
c) % of Plan = 120%
d) Results + (%oFPlan * 0.001) = 600.0120
```

I want Excel to show d) as 120% and ignore the 600.0

It should end up looking like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of what you expect the output to look like? Having trouble understanding what you expect, but I know a few different hacks that will probably get what you need.

Comment: Also, 600 + 120% = 601.20

Comment: You mean the graph?  or a screenshot of the actual cell?

Comment: What do you want the graph/chart to look like?

Comment: That's a good point let me adjust my question a bit to reflect that

Comment: `Mod(Results + (%oFPlan * 0.001),1)*10`

Comment: Can't be a formula, MUST be a number format, as I NEED to preserve the fact that there's still 600 before it, otherwise the 120% will appear at the bottom of the chart

Comment: What you actually want to do is plot the "600" but overwrite the data label with "120%".

Comment: That's exactly correct.  My first thought was to embed the 120 into the 600 somehow and just display the 120 part, but if you have another clever idea to achieve this I'm all ears!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by assigning the data labels from a different range, so let's say you have a chart like this, and you want the data labels to be 120% and 150% respectively, instead of 600 and 500.

[image]

Now, in older versions of Excel there was an option in the Chart dialog that allowed you to reassign the data labels *formula*, but it's either no longer present in Excel 2010, or I just can't find it (I use VBA for most things like this).

And even if do that, you're stuck with using one or the other (600 or 120%, but not both). To show both (600 inthe base, 120% above) you need two series of data.

**Add a *duplicate* series to the chart:**

[image]

**Select that series and do Overlapped 100%:**

[image]

**Format the new series**

For this example I use "No Fill" (or set the series order to "1" to put it *behind* the existing series; may or may not be possible depending on the rest of your chart). There are some quirks about series with "No Fill" so I usually prefer to make them White and push to Series Index = 1 so they appear "behind" other series.

[image]

**Select the data labels now, and run VBA procedure as follows.**

Note that some of the above steps could be baked in to the VBA, but the implementation will be largely dependent on your chart & worksheet structure.

```
Sub Data_Labels()
'Data_Labels Macro
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cht As Chart
Dim srs As Series
Dim dl As DataLabels
Dim rng As Range
Dim pt As Point
Dim p As Integer
Set ws = ActiveSheet

'Ensure the user selects some DataLabels
If TypeName(Selection) <> "DataLabels" Then
    MsgBox "Please select data labels to overwrite", vbInformation
    GoTo EarlyExit
End If

'Get a handle on the chart & data labels objects
Set dl = Selection
Set cht = Selection.Parent.Parent.Parent

'Prompt the user for new labels
Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
            "Please select the values to use for the data labels", _
            "Overwrite data labels", _
            Type:=8)

'Sanity check:
Do While rng.Cells.Count <> dl.Count
    Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
        "The number of cells in your selection does not match the number of data labels, please try again.", _
        "Overwrite data labels", _
        rng.Address, _
        Type:=8)

Loop

Set srs = dl.Parent
'## Iterate the points in this series
For p = 1 To srs.Points.Count
    Set pt = srs.Points(p)
    '##Overwrites the text with formula reference to the specified cell
    pt.DataLabel.Text = "='" & ws.Name & "'!" & rng.Cells(p).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
Next

EarlyExit:

End Sub
```

**The result**

You should get a chart which looks like so (you can delete the Legend, or individual LegendEntry per series):

[image]

As this chart's data labels for this series now contains a *formulaic* reference to the cells, those cells *can* contain formula to arrive at your 120% or whatever.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I'm leaving original answer because it's very versatile, but this may also be accomplished using a "Stacked Column" chart. However, I haven't tried testing this with any more complicated chart, and from memory, there are some challenges to using Stacked Columns along with additional chart types or series in the data, and that may not work for your purposes.

Build a stacked column chart, using a formula that results in the *integer* representation of the % value, e.g., "120" instead of "1.2" or "120%".  Format the series to be invisible/no fill, and adjust the position of data labels to Inside Base:

[image]

Then apply number format to the **cells** via custom format as: `General""\%""`

Then ensure the series' data labels are "Linked to Source":

[image]

Results as below:

[image]

Comment: This isn't "perfect" as it would be nicer to do it just with number formatting, however that might not be possible anyway and the only way to do this seems to be resorting to VBA.  That's fine in this situation.  Anyway, this worked so I'm giving you the green check!

Comment: Even with number formatting, you'd still need a second series (else, where does the "600" come from in the base of the column?). I doubt it's possible with number format, because you're also trying to perform mathematical operation on the value to derive the format (e.g., subtracting the integral, and multiplying the decimal, etc.).

Comment: This can also be done by aligning TextBoxes above the *single* series, but that approach is funky, and a lot less dynamic (i.e., the text box values won't update automatically with the cell contents, unless additional VBA used to handle that).

Comment: There's also a hack way to do this using a Stacked Column chart with a custom number format, it may not work on a complex chart like you're doing, but it would be worth a shot. Added some detail on that in revision to my answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

That would be *very* confusing to folk maintaining your spreadsheet.

As an alternative, consider introducing another row or column, where cells in that area have the formula

`=Mod(<range>, 1)`

Where `<range>` corresponds to a cell that you had wanted to format. This will extract just the decimal part, which you can format as a percentage.

Comment: Can't be a formula, MUST be a number format, as I NEED to preserve the fact that there's still 600 before it, otherwise the 120% will appear at the bottom of the chart.  See my update, with a screenshot of the chart I'm trying to produce